# How to sum specific row values together in Sparse COO matrix to reshape matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse coo matrix built in python using the scipy library. An example data set looks something like this:

```
>>> v.toarray()
array([[1, 0, 2, 4],
       [0, 0, 3, 1],
       [4, 5, 6, 9]])
```

I would like to add the 0th index and 2nd index together and the 1st index and the and 3rd index together so the shape would change from 3, 4 to 3, 2.

However looking at the docs their [sum function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.sum.html) doesn't support slicing of some sort. So the only way I have thought of a way to do something like that would be to loop the matrix as an array then use numpy to get the summed values like so:

```
a_col = []
b_col = []
for x in range(len(v.toarray()):
    a_col.append(np.sum(v.toarray()[x, [0, 2]], axis=0))
    b_col.append(np.sum(v.toarray()[x, [1, 3]], axis=0))
```

Then use those values for `a_col` and `b_col` to create the matrix again.

But surely there should be a way to handle it with the `sum` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the values with a simple loop and 2d slicing and than take the columns you want

```
v = np.array([[1, 0, 2, 4],
              [0, 0, 3, 1],
              [4, 5, 6, 9]])

for i in range(2):
    v[:, i] = v[:, i] + v[:, i+2]

print(v[:, :2])
```

Output

```
[[ 3  4]
 [ 3  1]
 [10 14]]
```

Comment: This is good, however it doesn't over rite the matrix values, as I mentioned v is a `sparse.coo_matrix` I tried to over rite the `v.data` array, but then there is a mismatch of rows/cols/data lengths

Comment: @mp252 I don't know much about sparse, but can't you convert it to a `numpy` array and than back to what you need?

Comment: Yes, that did work! I plugged it back into a new matrix and it worked, although I had to do a deepcopy but that is ok. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `csr_matrix.dot` with a special matrix to achieve the same,

```
csr = csr_matrix(csr.dot(np.array([[1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1]]).T))
#csr.data
#[ 3,  4,  3,  1, 10, 14]
```